# Bluetooth mouse can't connect to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, mouse

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04
I have a Huawei cd20 bluetooth mouse. When I go to the bluetooth page in Ubuntu settings and click on the season, after trying to connect, it is displayed on setup again!
I reset my mouse but it still did not change :(
My Ubuntu can connect to my Bluetooth headset without any problems and only with this mouse.
I tried internet solutions but got no answer.
I also installed Blueman, but when I try to connect with Blueman this season, the following error is displayed:
Connection Failed: Software caused connection abort

Is this problem repairable? and if no, Is this problem in Ubuntu 20.04? if I install an older version of Ubuntu, this problem will be fixed?
My device is dual boot and Windows 10 is also installed on it.

Answer (score 2):

This problem was fixed in kernel v5.11
I upgraded my kernel version and the mause connected

Comment: How you upgraded kernel?

Comment: Read this tutorial :
https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/02/linux-kernel-5-11released-install-ubuntu-linux-mint/

Comment: Thanks, i upgraded to 5.12 now.